# Tell IntelliJ via build.gradle file to set -parameters flag for javac

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, parameters, javac

Is it possible to tell IntelliJ via the `build.gradle` file to set the `-parameters` flag for the Java compiler automatically in its preferences?

IntelliJ should set [in its settings in *Additional command line parameters*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.3/java-compiler.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2018.3&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product#javac_eclipse%20in) the `-parameters` flag.

---

Gradle automatically sets the `-parameters` flag:

```
> Task :compileJava
Args for for compileJava are [-parameters]

> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :bootJar
> Task :jar SKIPPED
> Task :assemble

> Task :compileTestJava
Args for for compileTestJava are [-parameters]

> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
```

Comment: Currently it's not possible. There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As y.bedrov mentioned in a comment IntelliJ currently doesn't support this behaviour: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154038

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-parameters"
}
```

Comment: No. IntelliJ should set here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.3/java-compiler.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2018.3&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product#javac_eclipse in its settings in _Additional command line parameters_ the `-parameters` flag.

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown I'm almost positive that InlettiJ will figure it out and put your arguments as additional parameters if you try to add them as I described.